# Plymouth Boot Screen hang

Tags: centos, troubleshooting

Centos 7 unable to boot normally hangs on plymouth screen.
And gives this.

Warning dracut

Centos 3.10.0.514.26.2.el7.
Kvm was installed.

[image]

When tried to boot in rescue mode it give this error with 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you able to use any other kernel available ?

Comment: I tried every available kernel and the rescue mode. Still no luck.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess configurations, daemons and the context of the failure? The question is TOO vague.

Comment: Which information do you require. I have mentioned kernel version.

Comment: @Mongrel any luck using live cd ?

Comment: I have connected external hdd to the system. Trying to mount it. And reinstall the kernel.

Comment: External disk not getting mounted.